# Create service tomcat - Start and Shutdown

Tags: linux, apache, unix, tomcat, ubuntu

I installed the apache tomcat but to start the service, i have to go to the path $HOME/apache-tomcat-8.0.28/bin and run the script ./startup.sh to start and ./shutdown.sh to shutdown. How can I make like

> service tomcat start
>
> service tomcat stop

or another way for not need to go to the path of the tomcat on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /etc/init.d/tomcat stop 
>   /etc/init.d/tomcat start